# ODBC: Export from Microsoft Access to Postgres fails

Tags: postgresql, ms-access, odbc

I have a large database that I am currently exporting from Microsoft Access (Version 2006 Build 13001.20384) to PostgreSQL 10.12 (Ubuntu 10.12-0ubuntu0.18.04.1). So far this worked very well, but I have problems with one particular table. When I start the export, I get the following error message:

> ERROR: syntax error at or near '/';
> Error while executing the query (#1)

Unfortunately I do not know how to deal with this error message and I have not found any information about this message on the Internet. Maybe someone here can help me.

Comment: You say "with one particular table"... maybe the name of that table or a column name of that table is a keyword for postgresql and not for access (it seems the name contain a '/'). Try to split the import if you don't know the table to isolate the problem. E.g. divide the query in 2 halves, then do the same for the half that give the syntax error. If you update your question with the table definition that gives error we can help you find the exact problem if you can't figure it out.

Comment: Can you detail the steps you are taking to do the export/import? In particular the actual query(s) used? Also where is the error message showing up?

Comment: @Fil Thank you very much for the hint to the PostgreSQL keywords. I found out that there were column names that contained single quotes and double quotes at the end of their names. Microsoft Access seems to have no problems with this, but PostgreSQL does. After removing these characters, the export ran without further problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[I copy my previous comment, since it contains useful content for the solution, so this question can appear as solved... and it contains also suggestions for someone in the future with the same problem.]

You say "with one particular table"... maybe the name of that table or a column name of that table is a keyword for postgresql and not for access (it seems the name contain a '/').

Try to split the import if you don't know the table to isolate the problem. E.g. divide the query in 2 halves, then do the same for the half that give the syntax error. If you update your question with the table definition that gives error we can help you find the exact problem if you can't figure it out.